# Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS) spec file headers

Tags: astronomy, software, data-analysis, data

I downloaded [spectra](http://dr12.sdss3.org/spectrumDetail?mjd=52233&fiber=331&plateid=753) from Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS), which has the following column headers `flux, loglam, ivar, and_mask, or_mask, wdisp, sky and model` (determined by `tdump` and `tprint` in `pyraf.stsdas`).

I know about `flux, loglam, sky and model` but I wanted to know what are the other headings are and where are they used. ['loglam' is the log10(wavelength)]

Also, is there any way from which I can determine redshift using the SDSS spectra, by not looking on the quasar page.

Answer (score 1):

The answers can be found on the [Documentation page](https://data.sdss.org/datamodel/files/BOSS_SPECTRO_REDUX/RUN2D/spectra/PLATE4/spec.html):

```
HDU 1 (extname COADD): Coadded Spectrum from spPlate

Binary table with columns:
                        Required  Columns 
Name      Type      Comment
flux      float32   coadded calibrated flux [10-17 ergs/s/cm2/Å]
loglam    float32   log10(wavelength [Å])
ivar      float32   inverse variance of flux
and_mask  int32     AND mask
or_mask   int32     OR mask
wdisp     float32   wavelength dispersion in pixel=dloglam units
sky       float32   subtracted sky flux [10-17 ergs/s/cm2/Å]
model     float32   pipeline best model fit used for classification and redshift
```

AND and OR masks denotes rows where data is flagged in all or one columns, respectively.

As for redshift determination from SDSS spectra; you can identify emission line features like e.g. the H$\alpha$ - [N II] triplet around 6700 Å restframe, of the O II 3727+3729 doublet, or the H$\beta$ + [O III] 4959+5007 complex, and dividing their observed wavelengths by their restframe wavelengths.

Comment: Can you explain 'Flaged'

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "flagged". You could also say "masked" - marked that for some reason there is something wrong with the data in that column. I do not know which masking system they use, so I would probably use the "or" mask to discard data where this is set.